# Upload more than one ASP.NET project on server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm making a website that has an Admin Panel and a main design for the users. I want to make these two parts in separate projects. When I finish is it possible to upload both projects on the server or I can upload two projects only if one of them is the user interface and the other one is the logic (for example just classes)?

Comment: `(just classes)` is yours business logic?? then you need to just add reference to your main projects.

Comment: But what if it is not just buisness logic? There are .aspx pages in both projects.

Comment: why there is need to upload it as different projects if it belongs to same projects

Comment: Ganesh, see my answer below. There are good reasons to architect the application this way.

Comment: Because there are many pages and if they are in one project it will be a bit messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break your application into as many sub-sites as you want, and host each independently. This actually makes a lot of sense from a scalability perspective because you have the choice of hosting them all on one IIS box to start with, then as demand on your app grows, you can move them to separate IIS boxes.  If you write your code well, you can even have multiple servers running the same components (e.g. the web front-end) to give them better availability.  It also lets you do networking stuff (e.g. firewall, ACLs) to limit access to the admin components.  This is how SharePoint does it.

To be clear, though, IIS isn't going to host "projects" from Visual Studio, it's going to host Web Applications (so, anything in the ASP.NET family of projects, such as ASP.Net Web Applications, Web Services apps, etc).  Things that expose a network connection, *not* pure code libraries (e.g. "just classes".  Those you'll make references to inside your web apps and package them together for deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can I ask you only one more question? Can I access files that are in folder in the sub-site from the main site?

Comment: Yes, if you normally could (file permissions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes both can be two separate websites or one can be top level site and other a subsite under it